# Maven site migration - how to handle it?

Tags: java, maven, maven-site-plugin

Maven sites can discover Maven sites from dependencies using the `<url>` from the respective pom. These urls are usually hard-coded in the pom or one of its parent poms.

At the moment, we use the Nexus 2.14 site urls which have a path like

```
http://somerepo:8081/nexus/...
```

When we migrate to Nexus 3 or Artifactory, these urls will change, meaning that all links between sites of our artifacts will break.

How can we avoid this?

Answer (score 2):

From [sonatype help](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/2016/05/11/migrating-to-nexus-repository-3-easy-peasy/)

> 1. Finalize migration in Nexus Repository Manager 3
> 2. Shutdown Nexus Repository Manager 2
> 3. Shutdown Nexus Repository Manager 3
>
> Reconfigure it to run on the original port and context of Nexus
>   Repository Manager 2, for example port 8081 and /nexus context.
>
> Start Nexus Repository Manager 3
>
> Congratulations – you are done. Depending on your specific setup e.g.
>   usage of an external reverse proxy server around the repository
>   manager the detailed config steps will vary a little bit, but the
>   general approach is the same.
>
> All external settings.xml, .npmrc and similar config files using
>   repository URLs will continue to work in Nexus Repository 3, so you
>   wont have to reconfigure any client tools.

That mean that If you configure Nexus 3 correctly, your URLs will be the same and you don't need to change your poms.

Comment: The migration from Nexus 2 to Nexus 3 will not manipulate existing poms. Therefore, these links will break. I do not see anything in this answer that relates to my problem.

Comment: Sonatype says clearly that if you update your repository and configure it with same ip, port, tc (same url) you don't need to change anything in your poms because URLs are the same. All depending on how you configure your new repo. Read the sonatype help because it's so clear.

Comment: Ok, then please edit your answer so that it becomes clear that the URLs are unchanged. Does not solve the problem for other migrations, though. But thanks, this is a good hint for Nexus 2 -> Nexus 3.

Comment: My answer says:"All external settings.xml, .npmrc and similar config files using repository URLs will continue to work in Nexus Repository 3, so you wont have to reconfigure any client tools." And maven is like a client tool...

Comment: I'm sorry, but firstly, without ever mentioning the word "site" you cannot really answer a question on sites, and secondly, Stackoverflow does not allow me to undo my downvote unless you edit.

Comment: Edited with a mention to the URLs